# XYZ points for terrain models in different resolutions from a PostGIS server

Tags: postgis, terrain

I have a grid of points in a PostGIS DB. This grid is in the resolution 1m and its around 100.000 Points large. Getting these points from the db works for me.
For example like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM punkte
WHERE ST_Intersects(geom, ST_MakeEnvelope(minlon, minlat, maxlon, maxlat, 4326));
```

This returns all points within this rectangle. Is it possible to return these points in a kind of resolution? so like "only return every second point" or only return points within 2m / 5m etc.?

I am trying to generate terrain meshes from these points and struggle to make different resolutions of these models.

Any idea how I would achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 1):

You can use row_number function to enumerate each row, and select where [modulu/remainder](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-math.html) is 0. To select every other row:

```
select sub.*
from 
(select *, row_number() over(order by st_y(geom) desc, st_x(geom) asc) as rownum
from test."Grid" 
where st_intersects(geom, st_makeenvelope(502029, 7111231, 552390, 7156100, 3006))) sub
where sub.rownum%2=0
```

Modify the order by expression to adjust how they are selected.

[image]

(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595809/skip-every-nth-result-row-in-postgresql)